# Обработка сочетаний клавиш в окне и их вызов в системе

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть окно WPF клиента с обработчиком и отправкой серверу

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
     byte[] keys = new byte[3]; //shortcut

     byte key = (byte)MouseAndKeyboardControl.Keyboard.ToFormsKey(e.Key);

     TcpStream.Send("192.168.0.100", 25565, new TcpStream.Message("key", key));
}
```

Сервер получает клавишу и вызывает нажатие клавиши в системе

```
static void Parser(TcpStream.Message mes)
{
     if (mes.Command == "key")
         MouseAndKeyboardControl.Keyboard.PressKey((byte)mes.Obj);
     if (mes.Command == "keys")
     {
         byte[] keys = (byte[])mes.Obj; //shortcut

     }             
}
```

---

```
public static class Keyboard
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

    private struct KeyboardEvent
    {
        public const uint KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001;
        public const uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;
    }

    public static Keys ToFormsKey(System.Windows.Input.Key wpfKey)
    {
        return (Keys)System.Windows.Input.KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(wpfKey);
    }

    public static void PressKey(byte key)
    {
        keybd_event(key, 0x45, KeyboardEvent.KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
        keybd_event(key, 0x45, KeyboardEvent.KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KeyboardEvent.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    }
}
```

Как передавать сочетание клавиш серверу и вызывать их в системе?

Comment: Ааааа! Работа с сетью в OnClick! Мои глаза!

Comment: Что именно значит «вызывать их в системе»? Вы имеете в виду «отправить в активное окно»? Тогда вам может пригодиться [`SendKeys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Не очень понимаю как работает SendKeys
Я пытаюсь сделать подобие TeamViewer, чтоб была обработка ctrl+c, win+r, ctrl+alt+del и так далее, при том что приложение которое это делает не будет иметь фокус

Comment: Если вам нужна функциональность наподобие TeamViewer, вы начали не там. Простые приложения не получают Alt-Tab, Win+R или Ctrl+Alt+Del, вам нужно опускаться на оконного менеджера (для Alt-Tab) или глубже, на уровень драйвера клавиатуры (для Ctrl+Alt+Del).